# associate button with keypad

Tags: javascript

I have the folloing calculator: http://jsfiddle.net/4YT3W/

Ok i don't know if this is possible but: when you click on a button it has some default css attached to it. But when i press 1 from my keypad nothing is happening(meaning that my 1 button doesn't recieves any press).. so how can i do that?

I tried my best to explain what i want:)

I will have to add functions on any button i have?

this is what keys are accepted to the input (in case you got stuck)

```
function onlyNumbers(evt)
{
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

        if ( (charCode >=42) && (charCode <= 57)  ){
            return true;
        }

        if(charCode == 61){
            return true;
        }

         return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you have NumLock turned on?  It works fine for me...

Comment: when you press 1 on your keypad it makes the <button>1</button> interact like when you press it with your mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your javascript code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    var n = event.keyCode - 48;
    if (n >=0 && n <= 9) {
        calculator.result.value += n;
    }
});
```

you may want to add more keys yourself.

http://jsfiddle.net/LgjLM/